# can't connect Socket when not in same IP range. (subnet)

Tags: java, sockets, connection, subnet

When running a ServerSocket on a machine A with ip 145.74.217.109
And then trying to connect to machine A using machine B with ip  145.74.219.103 I am unable to connect.
But when using machine C with ip 145.74.217.180 it works.

Iam not sure if this is solvable in code or its just network settings. If It is network issues is there another way to go around this problem or would I need to go away from sockets to ...?

Machine A:

```
public void run() {
        try {
            sock = new ServerSocket(Constants.PORT);
            for (;;) {
                Socket newsock = sock.accept();

                System.out.println("Accepting new player: ");

                new PaintballPlayer(newsock);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IO error " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("End!");

        try {
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Machine B, C :

```
socket = new Socket(ip, Constants.PORT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look at the IP us server has IP `145.74.217.109` IP with `145.74.217.180` are able to connect while  `145.74.219.103` is not being able to connect it means subnet  `145.74.219.X` has no access to  `145.74.217.X` that is why it is not being able to connect. It is network setting ask you network administrator for that. Make your both machine have same subnet mask

Comment: Ok thats what I thaught shame theres no way around it. Thanks.

Comment: @zaffargachal How i can connect two machines on different subnets using sockets? i am able to ping those machines but socket doesn't work.

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 make sure port are open and accessible to each other. Try telnet command to check if port is open and accessible form that machine

Comment: @zaffargachal I am able to ping and ssh to those machines but when i try to use java sockets , it gives time out exception. May be the reason is different subnets! Bcz one IP on my LAN network belongs to Class B and my IP belongs to class C range. Am i right ?